# How should I program this ratings feature to minimize concurrency issues?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm writing a feature for a Symfony application that allows users to submit ratings for a product. I calculate the average value of ratings for a product after each rating is cast so that I don't need to run potentially expensive `AVG()` queries every time I need the average rating.

Here's a simple function that calculates the average rating and saves it:

```
public function calculateAndSaveAverageRating(Product $product)
{
    // Run the SUM() query and return a float containing the average,
    // or null if there are no ratings for the product.
    $calculatedAverage = $this
        ->em
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->findAverageRating($product);

    // Lookup an existing ProductRatingAverage entity if it exists. This
    // stores the average value of ratings for each product. Returns null
    // if there is no existing entity.
    $existingAverageEntity = $this
        ->em
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductRatingAverage')
        ->findOneBy(array('product' => $product));

    // Save the calculated average if we got a non-null value. Otherwise
    // there are no ratings for this product, so delete the existing
    // average entity if it exists.
    if ($calculatedAverage) {
        // If we have an existing average entity, update it. Otherwise
        // create a new one and store the average.
        if ($existingAverageEntity) {
            $existingAverageEntity->setAverage($calculatedAverage);
        } else {
            $existingAverageEntity = new ProductRatingAverage();
            $existingAverageEntity->setProduct($product);
            $existingAverageEntity->setAverage($calculatedAverage);
            $this->em->persist($existingAverageEntity);
        }
    } else {
        if ($existingAverageEntity) {
            $this->em->remove($existingAverageEntity);
        }
    }

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

But there are some concurrency concerns here. Here's two of them:

1. If two users submit ratings for a product with no prior ratings at the same time (or very close), then this code will attempt to create two average rating entities for the same product, when there can be only one (database unique constraints).
2. If two users submit ratings for a product that has prior ratings at the same time (or very close), then this code will probably exclude one of those ratings from the average value calculated.

I could take a different approach: Place an expiring cache in front of the query that runs the `AVG()` query, and have it expire every 1 hour or something. However, I run into the same problems: If two visitors trigger a cache refresh at the same time, there are the same concurrency issues present.

How should I design this code to minimize concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for concurrency are usually locking mechanisms. Sometimes is only necesary one row lock, and other times locks the whole table.  The first transaction apply a table lock and after that the rest of the transactions for search or modify data remains waiting until the first one explicitly perform the unlock. I recommend you read the following link http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support.